# Find the text starting with another text

Tags: c, string

Is there any method in `C` can find a text within another text?

For example, `text = "abaHello"`, `textneedtoSearch = "Hello";`.

If the `text` contains `"Hello"`, `return true, else return false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Character and string searching functions](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/string_handling.html)

```
`char *strstr( const char *s1,  const char *s2)`
```

> returns a pointer to the first
>   instance of string s2 in s1.  Returns
>   a NULL pointer if s2 is not
>   encountered in s1.

---

In additon,

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

> `strcmp`  compares the string s1 to the string s2.  The function returns 0 if they are the same, a number < 0 if s1 < s2, a number > 0 if s1 > s2.
>
> This is one of the most commonly used
>   of the string-handling functions.

And check this link for anything about string functions in C, [C string functions](http://www.edcc.edu/faculty/paul.bladek/c_string_functions.htm)

Answer (score 10):

Use `strstr`, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html

Answer (score 3):

The `C` function `strstr` returns a pointer to the start of the word you were looking for if it is contained in the text you were searching in, or `NULL`, if it does not contain the word you are looking for.

Syntax:

```
char *p = strstr(wheretolook,whattolookfor);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (strstr(text, textneedtoSearch) != NULL)
  printf("found\n");
```

Comment: if so, strstr(text, textneedtoSearch) == text

Comment: for an initial string, `!strncmp(text, textneededtoSearch, strlen(textneededtoSearch))` is probably better. It doesn't have to search through the whole `text`.

Comment: Agreed with that, but if it's a specific case of the general question, you still have to use strstr.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a text on string file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
        char  tmp[256]={0x0};
        while(fp!=NULL && fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp),fp)!=NULL)
        {
        if (strstr(tmp, argv[2]))
        printf("%s", tmp);
        }
        if(fp!=NULL) fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```