# C language: find out if string s2 exists in s1

Tags: c, char

Is there any C function to check if string s2 exists in s1?

> ```
> s1: "CN1 CN2 CN3"
> s2: "CN2"  or  "CG2"
> ```

s1 is fixed, and I want to check whether variants of s2 exists in s1 or not.

I am using C not C++.

Comment: Like [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)?

Comment: @Blastfurnace - I don't like that as a duplicate, that question is poor at best, and is asking for a non-std C function, strstr() happens to be the most upvoted answer, but it doesn't answer the question and it's not really a good duplicate. [Find the text starting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224476/find-the-text-starting-with-another-text) would be better.

Comment: @Mike: I agree, yours is better. That's all I could find after a brief search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strstr`. See [strstr documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)

`function strstr`

> char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
>
> Finds the first occurrence of the byte string substr in the byte string pointed to by str.

An example usage looks like the following:

```
 const char *s1 = "CN1 CN2 CN3";
 if (strstr(s1, "CN2") == NULL) //^^!=NULL means exist
 {
     //does not exist
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr):

```
#include <string.h>

if (strstr(s1, s2) != NULL)
{
    // s2 exists in s1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you should use strstr(). Adding a link to the GNU C documentation for strstr() since you mentioned you are using C not C++, however, the C++ documentation for this function is suitable for C too.

[GNU C String Search Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Search-Functions.html#Search-Functions)